# Changing the Order of Integration in a Triple Integral

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, bounds-of-integration

I'm currently studying for my multivariable calculus exam and I've come across a problem that I can't seem to solve. I have a triple integral with the order of integration $dz \, dy \, dx$ and I need to change it to $dx \, dy \, dz$. The original integral is:
$$ \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{2x} \int_{x^2 + y^2}^{x + y} dz \, dy \, dx $$

I attempted to change the order of integration by analyzing the region of integration in the $x y z$ space. The limits for $z$ are given by the plane $z = x + y$ and the paraboloid $z = x^2 + y^2$. The limits for $y$ are from $0$ to $2x$, and for $x$ from $0$ to $1$.

I tried to express the limits of $x$ in terms of $y$ and $z$ by solving the equations of the plane and the paraboloid for $x$, which gives me
$$ \sqrt{z - y^2} \leq x \leq z - y $$

For $y$, I considered the limits to be $ 0 \leq y \leq z $ and for $z$, $ 0 \leq z \leq 1 $. So the integral goes to:
$$
\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{z} \int_{\sqrt{z - y^2}}^{z - y} dx \, dy \, dz
$$

However, when I calculate the integral with these new limits, I get a result of
$$ \frac{1}{6} - \frac{7\pi}{64} $$
which suggests that my new limits of integration are not correct, because the result of the original integral is just $\dfrac{1}{6}$.

Could anyone provide some guidance on how to correctly change the order of integration in this case? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The problem is flawed. Note that over the point  $(1,2)$, the *lower* surface has height $5$ and the *higher* surface has height $3$. Note that $x^2+y^2=x+y$ is the circle of radius $1/\sqrt2$ centered at $(1/2,1/2)$; this curve falls partly inside the triangular projection of the volume into the $xy$-plane. So the original integral is not really allowed.

Comment: [[1]] I saw the Issue that you highlight , but I am not sure whether that is "a flaw" & "not allowed" , @TedShifrin , The Integral will Contribute $0$ Volume on that Circle & then Contribute Negative volume beyond that. [[2]] I think , the Issue which is the culprit here is that $z$ is not between $0$ & $1$ , It is between $0$ & $5$ & the other limits have to be suitably modified too.

Comment: @Prem: As far as I am concerned, this is not allowed in iterated integrals. I know no textbook that allows it.

Comment: The methodology you should use, if the original set-up were valid, is to *start* by finding the range of $z$ values in the region first, then the projection onto the $yz$-plane. For each point in that figure, you lastly figure out the range of $x$ values. Sometimes the answer depends on the location of $(y,z)$ and you have to split into two integrals.

Comment: That was the "Crux" of my Earlier Comment , @TedShifrin , the OP had the wrong $z$ range $(0,1)$ which should be $(0,5)$ : that will then necessitate reworking the $y$ range & then the $x$ range !

Comment: @Prem: Well, go on. It’s a mess to think through because of the issue I pointed out. What *is* the projection of the 3D region onto the $yz$-plane?

Comment: I was only referring to your Comment , @TedShifrin , "... is to start by finding the range of z values ..." & referring to OP guessing that "... my new limits of integration are not correct ..." , where I am Pointing out that $z$ range is Currently wrong.

Comment: AtomicZ, if you want to see some examples of switching the order of integration, see my [YouTube lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=exmZ4nuWGM4&list=PL5I-Eyk8l9FHdJUd9UujGcvumjCFPHbrd&index=62).